# my very simple firefox addon doesn't work, what I do wrong here?

Tags: firefox-addon

It contains only two files:

install.rdf:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>my_firefox_ext@localhost</em:id>
    <em:version>0.1</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:unpack>false</em:unpack>

    <!-- Firefox -->
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>21.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>25.0a1</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>

    <!-- Front End MetaData -->
    <em:name>my_firefox_ext</em:name>
    <em:creator></em:creator>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

and resources/main.js:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.gov",
  contentScript: 'document.body.innerHTML = ' +
                 ' "<h1>Page matches ruleset</h1>";'
});
```

It installs and shows in extension manager. There is no error message, but it doesn't work also. ( I don't know, is there a special console for addons errors?). The script should replace any content on *.gov sites with my test. This is simplest example I thought of to start learning firefox addons and I can't manage to go beyond this step.

Answer (score 2):

You should install the [Addon SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Installation) and use the accompanying [cfx tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_started_with_cfx).

Comment: Yes, I know that tool, but it is tiresome to compile an xpi everytime I change the source code. There's also tutorial on XRayWrapper: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Accessing_the_DOM - but there is no example xpi extension to just install and check everything is working. I do not know into what files to put the example code.